# Azure AD B2C with Azure AD - profile edit

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

If I've successfully configured Azure AD B2C to allow login using Azure AD accounts (per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-aad-custom), should I be able to set up custom policies to allow AAD-authenticated users to edit their profiles, overriding the default ProfileEdit policy?  If so, any hints as to how to tackle?  I am pretty sure I need to create a new UserJourney and a new ProfileEdit policy, but I'm not sure of the details.

thanks!

Martin

Comment: Hi Martin, have you configured both local and Azure AD accounts?

Comment: @chris-padgett -  yes, I have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enable an Azure AD-authenticated user to modify their account profile by including the Azure AD claims provider in the profile edit user journey as follows:

```xml
<UserJourney Id="ProfileEdit">
  <OrchestrationSteps>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsProviderSelection" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.idpselections">
      <ClaimsProviderSelections>
        <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="ContosoExchange" />
        <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
      </ClaimsProviderSelections>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="ContosoExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="ContosoProfile" />
        <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
          <Value>localAccountAuthentication</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserRead" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
          <Value>contosoAuthentication</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep> 
    <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="B2CUserProfileUpdateExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-ProfileUpdate" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="6" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" /> 
  </OrchestrationSteps>
  <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
</UserJourney>
```

This user journey prompts the end user to log in with either their local account or their Azure AD account and then, after reading the user object by either the object identifier (for the local account) or the alternative security identifier (for the Azure AD account), shows the profile editing page.